# NSTimer doesn't get fired repeatedly in my Swift code

Tags: swift, nstimer

I scheduled a timer in my viewDidAppear: method, but it just fire once and never fire again, the code is just like below

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: "test", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    timer.fire()
   }

func test() {
    print("timer test")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you didn't schedule it. Try this:

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("test"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

And get rid of timer.fire().

Be aware that if you create a timer in viewDidAppear then a new timer will be created every time your view appears.

Comment: I tested it, but when you get ride of timer.fire(), it just didn't get called once!

Comment: Sorry, I think I understand the problem, just the old initialiser method I used does not schedules it on the current run loop in the default mode.